# Yacc/Bison: The pseudo-variables ($$, $1, $2,..) and how to print them using printf

Tags: yacc, bison

I have a lexical analyser written in flex that passes tokens to my parser written in bison.

The following is a small part of my lexer:

```
ID [a-z][a-z0-9]*

%%

rule {
    printf("A rule: %s\n", yytext);
    return RULE;
}

{ID} { 
    printf( "An identifier: %s\n", yytext );
    return ID;
}

"(" return LEFT;
")" return RIGHT;
```

There are other bits for parsing whitespace etc too.

Then part of the parser looks like this:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define YYSTYPE char*
%}

%token ID RULE 
%token LEFT RIGHT 

%%

rule_decl : 
    RULE LEFT ID RIGHT { printf("Parsing a rule, its identifier is: %s\n", $2); }
    ;

%%
```

It's all working fine but I just want to print out the ID token using printf - that's all :).  I'm not writing a compiler.. it's just that flex/bison are good tools for my software.  How are you meant to print tokens?  I just get `(null)` when I print.

Thank you.

Comment: `$2` would be the `LEFT` token in that rule, wouldn't it? Wouldn't `$3` be the `ID` token you want to print out?

Comment: I thought $$ would be RULE, $1 is LEFT, $2 is ID and $3 is RIGHT?  No?  I'm probably wrong :s.  Anyhow.. printing out any of them ($$, $1, ...) all result in (null) so I'm doing something else wrong hmm.

Comment: @alemaster: @Chris Lutz is right; the tokens in the rule are numbered starting at 1. `$$` is a variable to which you can assign a pointer; that pointer will then be taken as the "result" of the rule and will be passed to other rules involving `rule_decl`.

Comment: Thank guys.  +1 to Chris.  Any ideas how to just print these things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not an expert at yacc, but the way I've been handling the transition from the lexer to the parser is as follows: for each lexer token, you should have a separate rule to "translate" the `yytext` into a suitable form for your parser. In your case, you are probably just interested in `yytext` itself (while if you were writing a compiler, you'd wrap it in a `SyntaxNode` object or something like that). Try

```
%token ID RULE 
%token LEFT RIGHT

%%

rule_decl:
    RULE LEFT id RIGHT { printf("%s\n", $3); }

id:
    ID { $$ = strdup(yytext); }
```

The point is that the last rule makes `yytext` available as a `$` variable that can be referenced by rules involving `id`.

Comment: Thank you Aasmund.. just trying to figure out why "error: ‘yytext’ undeclared (first use in this function)" is happening but I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @alemaster: Use `extern char yytext[];` in the topmost section, or possibly `extern char * yytext;`.

Comment: Fantastic thank you.  FYI:  Your second option worked but the first just made nothing print (rather than (null)).  Thank you :).

Comment: @alemaster: Good. I seem to recall having been bitten by different YACC implementations have different conventions for whether to use `char[]` or `char*`; that's why I provided both. There might also be an option for controlling the type, but I don't remember what it is.